# Change images programmatically when setOnTouchListener

Tags: android, onclick, imageview

I need to do a image changer when I click on the screen.

With this:

```
image.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_1);
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

I have another images, 5 or 6, and I want to change to another one when I click the image with the code above. How I can do this, when I click screen the imageview change to the next?

I could do this if I had a counter, but I think that this is not the best solution.

Comment: I want to make

tutorial_images.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_2);
tutorial_images.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_3);
tutorial_images.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_4);
...

on the same setOnClickListener

Comment: return true in ontouch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
int clicked = 0 ;

    images.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

     @Override
     public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
       switch (MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(motionEvent)) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        clicked++;
                        break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                        if(clicked == 1){
                            images.setImageResource(R.drawable.images_1);
                        }else if(clicked == 2){
                            images.setImageResource(R.drawable.images_2);
                        }else if(clicked == 3){
                            images.setImageResource(R.drawable.images_3);
                        }else if(clicked == 4){
                            images.setImageResource(R.drawable.images_4);
                        }else if(clicked == 5){
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                        return true;
                       break;
          }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am doing the next, but I don't know If there is another posibility:

```
images.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                int clicked = 1;
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                    if(clicked == 1){
                        images.setImageResource(R.drawable.images_1);
                    }else if(clicked == 2){
                        images.setImageResource(R.drawable.images_2);
                    }else if(clicked == 3){
                        images.setImageResource(R.drawable.images_3);
                    }else if(clicked == 4){
                        images.setImageResource(R.drawable.images_4);
                    }else if(clicked == 5){
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                    clicked++;
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Comment: This should not be as answer. Edit your question

Comment: Do you want touch or click event??

Comment: Whats the different between touch or click?

Comment: There is a vast difference between both. Please we clear what you want to implement. Anyways, it worked for you :)